# How to create sub arrays based on prefixes of string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a one-dimensional array with (a example):

```
{
    ["Pagamento_valor_liquido"]=> string(3) "111"
    ["Pagamento_valor_bruto"]=> string(3) "222"
    ["TipoPagamento_id"]=> string(3) "333"
    ["TipoPagamento_descricao"]=> string(3) "444"
}
```

and i need help to transforme this in two sub arrays:

```
{
    ["Pagamento"]=> array(2) {
        ["valor_liquido"]=> string(3) "111"
        ["valor_bruto"]=> string(3) "222"
    }
    ["TipoPagamento"]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(3) "333"
        ["valor_bruto"]=> string(3) "444"
    }
}
```

How do it in a generic way with this pattern (Father_son_name)?

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: its hard to know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array("Pagamento_valor_liquido" => "111", "Pagamento_valor_bruto" => "222", "TipoPagamento_id" => "333", "TipoPagamento_descricao" => "444");

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $name = explode('_', $k);
    $newkey = array_shift($name);
    $newname = implode('_', $name);
    $result[$newkey][$newname] = $v;
}
var_export($result);
```

Watch it in action [`here`](http://ideone.com/pmHHR)

Seems to be pretty generic for your purpose.

Comment: excellent but where is the values of arrays ('111','222','333','444')?

Comment: Doesn't have the values and will generate warnings on first pass when `$result[$newkey]` doesn't exist.

Comment: whoa! sorry, I've confused `$k` and `$v` in assignment to `$result[$newkey][$newvalue]`. FTFY.

Comment: Hm, as I recall with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` PHP would generate a notice if you tried to set a key on an uninitialized variable. However I just tried it on PHP 5.3.6 and it doesn't seem to generate the notice any more. It's a shame that PHP is getting more relaxed with age. Removed the downvote.

Comment: Same for PHP 5.2. Probably, in PHP 4 it was a `E_NOTICE`, but I can't recall it to say if you are right for sure. Maybe... PHP is pretty damn permissive, - yes :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function transform($array) {
    $return = Array();
    foreach($array as $keyname => $value) {
        list($key, $key2) = explode("_", $keyname, 2);
        if(!isset($return[$key])) $return[$key] = Array();
        $return[$key][$key2] = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}
```